# Reading a GPR with inline assembler

Tags: assembly, inline-assembly, cpu-registers, powerpc, wind-river-workbench

I am using the Diab C compiler (v5.9.4) for the PowerPC and I need to copy the content of a General purpose register into a function's local variable.

Are there any examples of how can I read a GPR and move its value in a variable in C?

Comment: I've never heard of this compiler.  Check the manual if it says anything about inline assembly.

Comment: It's a wind river compiler

Comment: That I found, too.  But no manual or anything.  Also, because it's a commercial compiler, there's no way for me to test a potential solution.

Comment: @fuz Can you please share please even your potential solution ?

Comment: I have none because I do not know what flavour of inline assembly (if any) the compiler supports.  If inline assembly is not supported, it might even be required to call an assembly function for this purpose.  Neverthless, I'm not quite sure what you are trying to achieve as general purpose registers are usually under the control of the compiler and do not hold predictable values at any point.

Comment: I set all the GPR in a assembly file to 0, and now i'm trying to read the current values of GPRs in C file if it's really 0 or not .

Comment: The C compiler is permitted to change the value of any general purpose register at any point in time (as long as it obeys the calling convention).  So there's no guarantee at all that any GPR will still hold 0 at any point in your C code, even right at the beginning of a function.  If it does so, then only by luck.

Comment: Also consider using a debugger to check the contents of registers.

Answer (score 1):

The compiler you mentioned is likely a variant of Clang or GCC. You can write inline assembly as below:

```c
// Read from GPR, change the '0' to the GPR you'd want
unsigned long gprv;
asm volatile("mr %0, 0" : "=r"(gprv));

// Writing to GPR
// Thanks Peter Cordes for pointing out clobber list
asm volatile("mr 0, %0" : : "r"(gprv) : "0");
```

Comment: Your "writing GPR" version is missing a clobber on the GPR you choose.  (Or it's *only* safe writing to the zero register, a no-op.)  To write any other GPR, `asm volatile("mr r5, %0" : : "r"(gprv) : "r5");`

Comment: Your first asm statement does not need to declare a clobber.  The only state it modifies is the register picked by the `"=r"` output constraint.  Telling the compiler we modified the register we wanted to read isn't necessary or helpful.